# Смена стилей input при нажатии на кнопку формы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, button, forms

имею форму на реакте примерно такого плана(несколько input и кнопка):

```
<div>
<div>text</div>
<input className="firststate"></input>
<div>text</div>
<input className="firststate"></input>
<button>Change</button>
</div>
```

Как сменить стиль input при нажатии на кнопку c одного на другой

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть примерно так, если это будет по типу toggle, если нет тогда просто убрать else.

```
  const somsing = () => {
    let currentClass = 'firststate';

    const changeClassHendler = () => {
       if (currentClass === 'firststate') {
         return 'new class'
       } else {
         return 'firststate'
       }
    }

   return (
     <div>
       <div>text</div>
       <input className={currentClass}></input>
       <div>text</div>
       <input className={currentClass}></input>
       <button onClick={changeClassHendler}>Change</button>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

currentClass можно будет перенести в state, там как ты захочешь.